# memberOf AD explorer search error

Tags: active-directory

I'm using AD Explorer from Sysinternals. I'm performing a memberOf search against the container OU= Alaska Users for the  following user:

```
CN=Doe.John,OU=Alaska Users,OU=Alaska,OU=someOU,DC=subdomain,DC=example,DC=com
```

with the following membersOf info:

```
CN=Alaska MC Admins,OU=Alaska User Groups,OU=Alaska,OU=Centers,DC=subdomail,DC=example,DC=com
CN=JCDC Student MC Admins,OU=User Groups,OU=someOU,DC=subdomain,DC=example,DC=com
```

and I'm getting no results when searching for 'Alaska' or 'MC Admin'. What am I doing wrong?

```
(memberOf=\*Alaska\*)
```

Edit:

In other words I'm looking for group membership for a member/group relationship I know exists, and it does not come up via

```
Search Container -> 
Class = Common Classes,
Attribute = memberOf,
Relation = Contains,
Value = Alaska
```

Thanks for the powershell tip. The QA guys might be stuck with ad explorer.

Comment: We now know what you are doing, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: FYI, the Windows world is irreversibly down the path of PowerShell, and if you don't learn it, you'll be left behind.  This is a trivial PowerShell command too, leaving really no reason to be using that SysInternals tool as crutch for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MemberOf is an array of objects.  I suspect, though don't know, that the SysInternals tool is looking for single "scalar" values, i.e.: not a composite value, such as an array or structure.  Totally agree with PowerShell comments above.  Sure, use AD Explorer / ADSIEdit to browse, Etc., but pick up PowerShell for anything more than that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not sure how to get this functionality to work in AD Explorer but I've been inspired to find good work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

Searching `memberOf` only works with `is` (not `contains`!) and a fully qualified group DN (wildcards are [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28984362/357313)).

Answer (score 0):

MemberOf is a property indicating what groups a user objects is a member of, which is an entirely different thing from its location in an AD/LDAP hierarchy.

Comment: Good point. Added additional info.